# Get currently matched route without parameters in Angular 13

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have route template `users/:id` which matches url such as `users/1`.

How can I get this route config (= `users:/id`) on current page?

I've tried using `Router` and`ActivatedRoute` but, I'm only able to get the url with parameters such as `users/1`.

This is a simplifies scenario, but basically I need to get the route config on any given page.

Comment: you can get it in `routeConfig.path` of `ActivatedRoute`

Comment: thats `null` unfortunately

Comment: where are you trying to get the info? intermediate/final matched component, a service,...

Comment: In `ngOnInit` of the component ;)